# Protractor with typescript cannot find module 'protractor' after successfully resolved

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor

This problem is killing me. Please help.
I have following file structure:

```
node_modules
    protractor
    typescript
package.json
register-popup.ts
```

The content of package.json

```
{
    "name": "typescriptProba",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
         "protractor": "^4.0.11",
         "typescript": "^2.0.10"
    }
}
```

The content of register-popup.ts:

```
import { ElementFinder, element, by } from "protractor";

export class RegisterPopup {
    public registerWithFacebookButton: ElementFinder = element(by.css('li.facebook a'));
    public registerWithGoogleButton: ElementFinder = element(by.css('li.google a'));
    public registerWithEmailButton: ElementFinder = element(by.css('li.email a'));
    public registerWithMobileButton: ElementFinder = element(by.css('li.natel a'));

    constructor () {}

    openPopup() {
        element(by.css('.account.user')).click();
        element(by.id('openRegister')).click();
    }

    openRegisterByEmailPopup() {
        this.registerWithEmailButton.click();
    }

    openRegisterByPhonePopup() {
        this.registerWithMobileButton.click();
    }
}
```

For compiling ts file to js file I am using following command:

```
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc "./register-popup.ts" --module commonjs --noResolve --traceResolution
```

After executing command I have following error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor'.
```

But my module trace resolution is like this:

```
======== Resolving module 'protractor' from '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/register-popup.ts'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module 'protractor' from 'node_modules' folder.
File '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor.ts' does not exist.
File '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor.tsx' does not exist.
File '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor.d.ts' does not exist.
Found 'package.json' at '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor/package.json'.
'package.json' has 'typings' field 'built/index.d.ts' that references '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts'.
File '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts', result '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts'
======== Module name 'protractor' was successfully resolved to '/Users/predraglazarevic/www/typescriptProba/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts'. ========
```

So I have

> Module name 'protractor' was successfully resolved

but still have error

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor'.

Why?

ANSWER

When I omit --noResolve flag it is working. So command should be

```
./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc "./register-popup.ts" --module commonjs
```

Comment: can you share your  `tsconfig` file as well?

Comment: there is no tsconfig file

Comment: I don't get it how are you compiling without a tsconfig file?

Comment: I think you can. Actually my ts file is compiled to js file, but with error above

Comment: When I omit --noResolve flag it is working. So command should be ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc "./register-popup.ts" --module commonjs

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the **moduleResolution** setting to **node** in my **tsconfig.json** file.

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

After that, I was able to import browser, etc... from protractor.

```
import { browser } from 'protractor'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your tsconfig.json, you see the typeRoots

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "path/to/transpiled/files",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

If you have any additional DefinitelyTyped modules, they will be picked up by the `typeRoots` directory in the local path: `node_modules/@types`.

Comment: Updating answer above. `@types/protractor` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
yarn install && yarn webpack:build
```

that should download all missing modules and rebuild the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't install protractor module/library in your local. So,

Run this command : npm install --save protractor. If it won't work.
Try this :

1. Open VSCode and click View -> Terminal
2. Navigate to the folder in which you want to install the protractor.
3. Install the Protractor using below command.

npm install protractor -g

4.Restart VSCode. It will add protractor.conf.js file in your local.